# Libraries for multi threading

Tags: multithreading

When multithreading a game what do i need to think about when picking the Libraries when developing for pc?
I have been looking at process.h and was wondering if there are any big downsides (like speed or stability) whit this library and if i should look at something else?

Comment: You should at least check if the functions and classes you use from that library are thread safe.

Comment: OffTopic. Programming related - belongs to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

The only decent C++ multithreading libraries are TBB and Microsoft's PPL. Picking anything else is begging for trouble.

Comment: Care to share answer to question: Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague ("a game"... any game?) but I doubt you will have trouble with a "library" so much as your actual engine design. The harder/est part is to code your engine in such a way is that multi-threading is implemented correctly; picking a library (probably more appropriately, a language) that handles this well is almost trivial.